# Complex gestures on the iPhone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, gesture-recognition, gestures

Is there a high level library that handles complex gestures l ike detecting triangles / loops / circles? Is it even possible to build such a library with what Apple already has?

Thanks,

Teja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "[Dollar Recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/)"... its pretty accurate and very easy to use from a single training template.  There is even an effort started for an [iPhone implementation](http://code.google.com/p/dollar-touch/), although its not been released yet.  An implementation is being used by [AlphaCount](http://alphacount.wordpress.com/).

Comment: This is great! I hope I don't run into any licensing issues if I try to implement this on the iPhone..